# How to find the nearest numeric values (also in decimal places) in SQL same as LIKE function

Tags: sql, decimal, sql-like, sql-function, sql-null

I want to find the nearest coordinates to validate the place name as the format type is FLOAT, then I cannot use LIKE function as it is only applicable for STRING format.

situation example;
my reference is (latitude, longitude) that have short decimal places such as (67.1, -69.2) where in the list the coordinates is at five decimal places.

so I need to use my reference coordinates to find any other coordinates that start with same reference coordinates.

I already use LIKE function but cannot use it as it is allowable for STRING only.

Comment: https://alikhallad.com/how-to-find-closest-locations-using-coordinates-with-sql/

Answer (score 0):

sorry if i misunderstood you but you could figure it out by simple math:

```
SELECT * FROM table_lat_len_tst;
```

[image]

```
SELECT 
    t2.id
    , t2.lat
    , t2.lon
    , ABS(t1.lat - t2.lat) diff_lat
    , ABS(t1.lon - t2.lon) diff_lon
    , ABS(t1.lat - t2.lat) + ABS(t1.lon - t2.lon) delta
FROM 
    table_lat_len_tst t1
        JOIN table_lat_len_tst t2 ON t2.id != t1.id
WHERE
    t1.id = 1 -- Neares to ID
ORDER BY
    delta
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY;
```

[image]

Let me know if it was helpful.

Comment: It is different, let me give example.

E.g.: I have three columns named station name, latitude, longitude.
Situation I have 1000 data entry, I got 200 nulls at station name column.

As alternative to fill the null; I match the nulls with available station name by using coordinates (lat,long).

station name, latitude, longitude = nulls, 41.79, -87.6, where I try to match with available data that have 5 decimal places.

method I have discovered was by using LIKE function but that is only for STRING.